# Castle.Windsor: Conditionally resolving an additional implementation

Tags: castle-windsor

I have a domain that looks something like this:

```cs
public interface IParent{ IChild[] Children { get; set; } }

public class Parent1 : IParent
{
    public IChild[] Children { get; set; }
    public Parent1(IChild[] children) { Children = children; }
}

public class Parent2 : IParent
{
    public IChild[] Children { get; set; }
    public Parent2(IChild[] children) { Children = children; }
}

public interface IChild{}
public class Child1 : IChild{}
public class Child2 : IChild{}
```

I use the `ArrayResolver` to get multiple children for the parents resolved.
What I need to have is that when I resolve `Parent1` I get only the `Child1` implementation (an possibly some more that are always present)
but when I resolve `Parent2` I want to add `Child2`.

My first attempt was this:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class BasicUnderstandingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CanAddImplementationInOverride()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Kernel.Resolver
                 .AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));

        container.Register(Component
            .For<IParent>().ImplementedBy<Parent1>());
        container.Register(Component
            .For<IParent>().ImplementedBy<Parent2>().Named("Parent2")
            .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IChild>().Eq<Child2>()));

        container.Register(Component
            .For<IChild>().ImplementedBy<Child1>());
        container.Register(Component
            .For<IChild>().ImplementedBy<Child2>());


        var p1 = container.Resolve<IParent>();
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Parent1>(p1);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, p1.Children.Length);

        var p2 = container.Resolve<IParent>("Parent2");
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Parent2>(p2);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, p2.Children.Length);
    }
}
```

But this fails on the first assert if both Implementations if `IChild` are registered and on the second assert if only the first implementation is registered.

Is there an elegant way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Shouldn't p2.Children.Length be 1 since you only registered a single "Child2"?

Comment: No, the point is to have Parent1 have only 1 Child and Parent2 2 children (Child1 and Child2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a **major hack**, but it was a fun little project.  I created a custom `ISubDependencyResolver` to handle this situation (kind of).  Instead of the ArrayResolver, try this one:

```
public class ParentChildResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public ParentChildResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        var number = model.Name.Substring(model.Name.Length - 1, 1);
        var childType = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}.Child{1}", model.Service.Namespace, number));
        var children = kernel.ResolveAll<IChild>().Where(c => childType.IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType())).ToArray();
        return children;
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return typeof (IChild[]).IsAssignableFrom(dependency.TargetType);
    }
}
```

It has a few major assumptions which makes it really hacky:

1. It only works for types named "Parent1" through "Parent9" (so it only matches up "Child1" through "Child9").
2. It assumes the Child implementations are in the same namespace as the Parent implementations (which may not work for you).
3. There's no error checking!

You can also get rid of the service override too since it wasn't doing anything.

I couldn't think of an easier way to do this since the kernel sees all of the children as IChild objects.  You need to see if those IChild objects are implemented by a certain type for the parent -- and I matched those up by the number suffix.

Like I said -- major hack.  :)

Comment: THis is no quite solving my problem (see my answer to your comment) but with some modifications I think I will get something like this to work.